# JSON error and Run script error

Tags: html, json

Apologies for any incorrect formatting I am new to these message boards

I am using HTML to customise a Textbox in Spotfire and although I get no errors in the Spotfire client I get the following error when I open the Spotfire analysis in Chrome

```html
{ "titleFontColor":"#999999", "value":<SpotfireControl id="98bb1934a3c14ca2ab598deb672b8e44" />, "valueFontColor":"#010101", "symbol":"%", "min":<SpotfireControl id="0a05e2f1c4094273870d97a23b69efe2" />, "max":<SpotfireControl id="033f79eeccdb46ef982262c3c8a4ed0e" />, "humanFriendly":false, "humanFriendlyDecimal":2, "gaugeWidthScale":2.5, "gaugeColor":"#ebebeb", "label":"", "labelFontColor":"#b3b3b3", "shadowOpacity":0.2, "shadowSize":5, "shadowVerticalOffset":3, "levelColors":["#a9d70b","#f9c802","#ff0000"], "startAnimationTime":100, "startAnimationType":"&gt;", "donutStartAngle":90, "hideValue":true, "hideMinMax":true, "hideInnerShadow":false, "noGradient":false, "donut":true, "counter":false, "decimals":0, "formatNumber":false,
"customSectors": [{
      "color" : "#D8181C",
      "lo" : 0,
      "hi" : 1
    },{
      "color" : "#F5CC0A",
      "lo" : 1,
      "hi" : 2
    },{
      "color" : "#50AF28",
      "lo" : 2,
      "hi" : 3
    }] }
```

I get the following

> Error - Unexpected token , in JSON at position 39.

I am very new to HTML and was wondering how I locate position 39 in order to try and find the error?

The second issue I am running into is that HTML displays the Donuts as I would expect in my Spotfire client but when I open the webplayer version the icons are not visible. I have to change tabs in the analysis and then return to the first page for the icons to appear. Is this likely to be an error in my HTML or an error elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Check this site out: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. It helps you validate/troubleshoot json data. You need to wrap all elements in quotes. <SpotfireControl id="98bb1934a3c14ca2ab598deb672b8e44" /> in this case.

Comment: Change it to wrap SpotfireControl in quotes and change quotes within that to apostrophes: "value":"<SpotfireControl id='98bb1934a3c14ca2ab598deb672b8e44' />"

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have several problems,

-First you have to put all this code in one line otherwise "]" or "}" will make an error

-Second you have unexpected characters "<" and "/>" in your json you have to clean your json.

Then you can do in javascript

```
console.log(your_var)
```

or

```
console.log(JSON.parse(your_var))
```

it will transform in json you json (which is in string format)

We need sources to check what can be the problem.